# How to unset default style's setter in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Style TargetType="{AnyParentClass}">
   <Setter Propery="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
</Style>
```

...

```
class MyControl : AnyParentClass { ...
```

Is there any way to let my control inherit it Foregrond from visual parents?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
<MyControl
Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
Path=Foreground}" />
```